# Adding table layout to AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display an AlertDialog (button OK) with the content being a TableLayout.

However, I would like the TableLayout creation to be programatically, by Java, as I need to add rows depeding on some variables.

Any Idea how to do that? 
Specifically:

1- Can an AlertDialog have TableLayout view, or does it only expect text so I should go with dialog?
2- How do I create TableLayout programmatically and add rows to it.

I have done it in xml but not sure in java
Help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: 1 and 2 are separate questions. so you may get better answers if you separate them into two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom Dialog?

1 - You can instantiate a Dialog as in `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, theme)`

2 - Then you can make a `dialog.setContentView(layout)`, find your tablelayout by id (`dialog.findViewById`)

3 - Then do what you need to do. I'd recommend putting this all in a separated method.

Comment: 1. Because  i needed the OK button that is shown by alert dialog
2. As I said in the question, I want to create a table layotu programmatically not from xml

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set whatever layout you desire to the dialog using it 'setContentView' method.

You can inflate ui from an xml file. Like

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View yourView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
alertDialog.setContentView(yourView);
```

The above code should work.

Comment: I need to create tablelayout programtically as I said in my question